# Script Activity Outputs

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, automationstudio, activities

I creasted a SSJS in Marketing Cloud under --> Automation Studio --> Activities --> Script , I was curious to know how I can view the results of Write statements in the script?
I am able to store data in Data Extension, but for development purpose would like to view the output for some complex scripts.
Thanks Sachi.

Comment: You can’t - for dev purposes, use CloudPages. You will be able to see the output of `Write` upon publishing the CloudPage.

Comment: Great, Thanks. But I get 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Where as the same SSJS code is running correctly in Script Activity.

Comment: Thanks @zuzannamj , there was some issue, so I was getting 500 Internal Server Error.
Once I fixed the script, it is working fine.

I am able to test in CloudPages.